# Asp.NET Core use scopes from ADFS to authorize access to web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, authorization, adfs

Might be an idiotic question, but I cand validate scopes in order to authorize request access to different web apis.

As an user, i have some scopes validated by ADFS, and base on one or more scopes I want to have access to API.

This is what I've tried to add in ConfigureServices() from Startup.cs:

```
// Policies
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Read",
        policy => policy.RequireClaim("Read")); // This is the scope
});
```

And my web api is decorated like this `[Authorize(Policy = "Read")]`

Even so I get 403, when i use the bearer token.

Answer (score 2):

Replace with this:
`policy => policy.RequireClaim("scope", "Read")); // This is the scope`
Apparently you have to tell it where to check the scope for.